# Why can't i copy and paste in Safari's textarea?

Tags: html, safari, textarea

I have a general textarea in a code like so:

```
<div><textarea></textarea></div>
```

However in Safari and Chrome I can not copy and paste. When I select text I can copy, but when I paste it just pastes an empty string. Anyone familiar with this problem and knows how to solve this? Its driving me mad.

PS I am running jQuery.

---

Ok the problem occurs in jqtouch.css and it's the line

```
body > * { 
    display:none;
}
```

---

```
body > * {
    left:100%;
}

body > .current {
    left:0px;
}
```

Does fixes the issue apparently but you dont want all views to be drawn.

---

If you hide the views in javascript like so $('body > *').css('display', 'none');. There is no problem again.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Put up a more thorough example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Does the same thing happen with JavaScript disabled?

Comment: Is this a jQuery issue or a browser/OS issue? Can you copy and paste from other textareas or inputs?

Answer (score 0):

It's been driving me crazy as well (on Chrome Canary).  It looks like this is a verified priority 1 regression in webkit (although it's been closed for some reason).  See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60057 for more details.